# Connection problem with msk using spring kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, aws-msk

[image]

So here on the aws instance we have tried to connect spring kafka with msk where it works with local kafka. next there is no ssl . I tried telnet its running. But while running the application this exception comes.

Our cluster of msk is in same vpc . all the broker connection configuration strings are fine

```
  Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers"));
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
```

Comment: Are you running this locally attempting to connect to the MSK? Or running an EC2 instance?

Comment: @JRK on ec2 instance

Comment: When your Spring Boot application starts, it should log (at INFO level) the ProducerConfig values used by the KafkaProducer. Search for `bootstrap.servers` in the log. What is the actual value?

Comment: @ChinHuang So as per the log image given producer config are not printed . it stops till admin client configs as it is not able to connect with msk. bootstrap.servers value i have printed on my local are the broker url which is coming perfect

Comment: What is the value of property `spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers`?

Comment: @DenisStafichuk that is the msk bootstrap server url

Comment: And not localhost:9092 or 127.0.0.1:9092, right?

Comment: @DenisStafichuk yes,The value showing in the screenshot is for admin config which is localhost:9092 .The msk bootstrap server url is set for producer & consumer config

Comment: You may want to check if there are security groups in place that allow the communication between your Spring Kafka machine and the MSK cluster.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with the solution where I used `Kafka-rest-proxy` provided by Confluent which I configured it with `AWS MSK` and it worked for me